# Firebase event listener never triggered (iOS app)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to do something when a event is triggered in my app, using Firebase Functions:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendIAPAnalytics = functions.analytics.event('IAP').onLog((event) => {           
    console.log("event done");
    return true;
});
```

My event "IAP" is marked as conversion.
The event appears in Analytics DebugView.

"IAP" event is called in my iOS app:

```
Analytics.logEvent("IAP", parameters: nil)
```

Function deployment is ok, without errors.

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/cmilliet/Documents/APP TEST/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (39.34 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function sendIAPAnalytics(us-central1)...
✔  functions[sendIAPAnalytics(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!
```

But nothing appears in Functions logs.

FYI, I have already implemented another function (onUpdate) without troubles.

What I missed?

Comment: Only conversion events from Analytics trigger Cloud Functions. Did you [mark `IAP` as a conversion event](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522?hl=en#enable)?

Answer (score 1):

Only conversion events from Analytics trigger Cloud Functions.

Since `IAP` seems to be a custom event, you need to [mark it as a conversion event](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522?hl=en#enable).

Comment: Nope sorry. Based on what you told us initially, I immediately though of the requirement that it's a conversion event. Now that you've confirmed that it already is, I don't know what else could cause it. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.